# Wiremock request not matching even with anyRequestedFor(anyUrl())

Tags: junit, wiremock

I have a java service and using junit 4.x as test framework. I am using the junit @Rule in test file like this:

```
  @Rule public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(12345);
```

This is the test case:

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws MessageException {
    stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/deal_catalog/v1/lookupId"))
      .willReturn(aResponse().withBody(
        "\"deal\": {" +
          "\"id\": " + dealId.toString() +
          "}"
      )));

    DoSomethingTriggersAHTTPCall();


    WireMock.verify(anyRequestedFor(anyUrl()));
```

I am trying to verify a request with a url path but it kept failing. So I decided to test the loosest condition but it is still failing for me. Really desperate, any suggestion?

```
Expected at least one request matching: {
  "method" : "ANY"
}
Requests received: [ {
  "url" : "/deal_catalog/v1/deals/lookupId?clientId=deal_catalog_team&inventoryProductId=3f4f32ff-80f6-40f9-8ae7-8a09ec3dafd2",
  "absoluteUrl" : "http://localhost:12345/deal_catalog/v1/deals/lookupId?clientId=deal_catalog_team&inventoryProductId=3f4f32ff-80f6-40f9-8ae7-8a09ec3dafd2",
  "method" : "GET",
  "clientIp" : "127.0.0.1",
  "headers" : {
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent" : "okhttp/3.13.1",
    "Host" : "localhost:12345",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip"
  },
  "cookies" : { },
  "browserProxyRequest" : false,
  "loggedDate" : 1619815885486,
  "bodyAsBase64" : "",
  "body" : "",
  "scheme" : "http",
  "host" : "localhost",
  "port" : 12345,
  "loggedDateString" : "2021-04-30T20:51:25Z",
  "queryParams" : {
    "clientId" : {
      "key" : "clientId",
      "values" : [ "deal_catalog_team" ]
    },
    "inventoryProductId" : {
      "key" : "inventoryProductId",
      "values" : [ "3f4f32ff-80f6-40f9-8ae7-8a09ec3dafd2" ]
    }
  }
} ]
```

#### ==== Update ====

I think I figured this out. I was doing a functional test on the behavior of an async process triggered by a message (pub/sub). The Processor interface is like this:

```
public interface MessageProcessor<T> {
    void process(ReceivedMessage<T> message);
}
```

The problem is that I didn't call the process method and test the behavior. Instead, I published a message to the in memory message queue and that triggers the `void process(ReceivedMessage<T> message);` asynchronously. I guess when `verify()` method is invoked, the outgoing http call in `process()` has not happened yet. But when wiremock generates the failure report, it already happened so the it is shown in the failure report.

After I switched to call `process()` directly in test, it passed.

Comment: Are you sure that your stub created is actually matching your request? I see a difference in the URLs you are passing in. I don't have a ton of experience with the `verify()` method, but it might not be showing correctly if there are no matched requests (as in, WireMock doesn't match any requests)

Comment: @agoff I think I figured it out. Let me update my question